# Lua: Is there a way to get a tables metatable

Tags: lua, metatable

Is there a way to get a tables metatable?
e.g.

```
local tbl = {}
setmetatable(tbl, {__call = function() print("tbl called") end})

-- how to get metatable of tbl?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getmetatable(tbl)` to get the assigned metatable (or `nil` if none is assigned).

Comment: Or the `__metatable` field of the metatable if set.